# Average length of every element in string array

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to get an average length of every element in my string array. But not sure with my code. Any suggestions?

```
public static double averageLength(String[] words, int count) {

        double countedLength = 0.0;


        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            countedLength += words[i].length();
            count++;
        }

        return (double)countedLength / count;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you having `count` as parameter? And if all array elements are unconditionally counted, why maintain a count at all when you can use `word`'s length?

Comment: it was part of the instructions to have count as a parameter.

Comment: Method: double averageLength(String[] words, int count)

Returns:
double, the average length of the first count words in the array words

Comment: Then your problem is that you're iterating until `words.length`. You need to change your loop declaration to `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)`. And remove `count++;` from the loop's body

Comment: Yep that solves my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Stream API for this task:

```
public static double averageLength(String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words)
                .mapToDouble(String::length)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: ...or just `.mapToDouble(String::length)`.

Comment: Oh my!=) Seems like somebody haven't woken up yet... Thanks.=)

Answer (score 0):

Change return to

```
 return (double)countedLength / words.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you average you need to divide by the number of elements you've summed up. Also in your method you don't need to pass the `count` variable as it's not used in your method.

```
public static double averageLength(String[] words) {
  double countedLength = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    countedLength += words[i].length();
  }
  return countedLength / words.length;
}
```

Just out of interest, you could always also use the `foreach` loop structure to iterate through the elements:

```
public static double averageLength(String[] words) {
  int countedLength = 0;
  for(String word : words) {
    countedLength += word.length();
  }
  return countedLength / words.length;
}
```

The result is the same however.